# Overflow menu background color is gone after changing styles to MaterialComponents

Tags: android, xml, android-theme, material-components, material-components-android

At first, My app use `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` style. But I changed it to Material Components `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">` (in order to use the tab's badge count of Material). So the style after changing is like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

After changing the style, the overflow menu background is now white. (It was green background with white text before with `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`). But now the background is white, and the text is also white.

Here is the xml for the toolbar:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/ev_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme">
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

and theme style of the toolbar:

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

I tried setting `<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/CustomPopup</item>` in the `AppTheme` with

```
<style name="CustomPopup" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

but still no luck.

The device I use to test uses Android 8.0, `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` is 28.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The background color of the popup in overflow menu is defined in the app theme by the attribute **`actionOverflowMenuStyle`**.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
   <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.PopupMenu.Overflow</item>
</style>
```

The `1.2.0-alpha02` [**fixed**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/aa7d83333e58de31ab37f0c11733cebf55d8e28e) a mixing between light and dark theme for this value.

You can also customize the popup using:

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        ../>
```

with:

```
  <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/...</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

You can also override the color without changing the drawable using the `android:theme` attribute in the `Toolbar`

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:theme="@style/MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar"
        ../>
```

Using:

```
  <style name="MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/custom</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Using `android:theme="@style/MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar"` within `MaterialToolbar` works for me. Beside, I have to add `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>` to make the text white. Thank you for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 4):

Another twist to the accepted answer above using MaterialComponents.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme.    -->
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/Theme.MyApp.PopupOverlay3</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyApp.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyApp.PopupOverlay3" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.PopupMenu.Overflow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyApp.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.MyApp.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

the key is, as you say the `actionOverflowMenuStyle` attribute is the key to success. Set this to a style which uses the `Widget.MaterialComponents.PopupMenu.Overflow` style. And then change the attributes you want to customize for the overflow menu.

RG

Answer (score 0):

you should add this code into toolbar, it will work

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/ev_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    **android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light**">
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I tried your solution also, The text of the toolbar and the menu is black, and the background of the overflow is white. Overriding some attributes did the work. However, I have to override 2 styles, one for the main theme (of the toolbar) and the other for the popup.